# Play 2.1.0 subproject logs issue

Tags: akka, playframework-2.1

I have included an akka 2.1 subproject to my play project. The logs however have stopped showing up in application.log now.

I'm using the basic mechanism to log akka 
private LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

What and where should be the config changes done to include these logs with my play application logs?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Akka log level changed from `INFO` to `WARNING` in Play 2.1.1.

You can set it back to `INFO` by adding the `play.akka.loglevel="INFO"` property in the `conf/application.conf` file.